# Why does it crash the second time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, crash

Hey guys,
  I'm new to Objective-C, and I'm making an app, and when you click on a table cell it does what it's supposed to, but when you go back and click on the cell the second time, it crashed with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".  Could you tell me what it means, and why is it only crashing the second time, and how could I fix it?  I'm pretty sure it's in this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    RaceData * data = [self.units objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ProtossInfo * info = [[ProtossInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProtossInfo" bundle:nil];

     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];

    info.title = data.titler;
    info.minerals.text = data.min;
    info.vespene.text = data.vesp;
    info.supply.text = data.sup;
    info.portrait.image = data.porty;

    [info release];
    [data release];

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're releasing `data`, which you didn't `retain`.

Comment: For future reference, you should [turn on](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16) `NSZombieEnabled` as an argument in your executable settings, which is enormously helpful for debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be doing the:

```
[data release]
```

...because 'data' wasn't obtained via an alloc, new, retained etc.
Most likely the reason it crashed the 2nd time around is the heap got corrupted by a double-free.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the code, you have written like

RaceData * data = [self.units objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

that means you are taking the reference of that specific object in to the "data" object.

but you are trying to release that object.

So the nil value will be replaced at that index in that "units" array.

So when you click second time you are accessing the properties(like titler,min etc...) from the nil object. But it doesn't have those. So it is crashing.

remove the [data release]; statement, then it will be resolved.

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 0):

You should not release the data come from [self.units objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
And, I think you should read [the apple's memory management guide.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)